# how to make aws instance to managed instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I am trying to use AWS Systems Manager for automation, but found many instances under my account aren't in the managed instances list, is there any commands to make the instances to be managed instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance are **automatically** registered with SSM if:

- they have installed and running SSM Session Manager **agent**
- they have **connectivity** to SSM services - either through the internet or VPC interface endpoints
- they have **instance role** attached with `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` policy
- there are **no explicit denies** that would prohibit using the SSM

Comment: Thanks, the SSM agent already ran on the instances, so I can create an IAM role then assign the role to the instances, is that right?

Comment: @joehuang yes. And then wait few minutes and it should register.